# How to get the customer_id to a second table from the customer_id of the first table?

Tags: mysql, html, jsp

A form is used to get information from a customer.
this form has several fields.
the data from several fields have to be saved in a one column.
the rest needed to be saved in another table.

The below is the cord that i am using

```
package web.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.ead.DBConnect;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class New
 */
public class CustomerReg extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CustomerReg() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        //String Password = request.getParameter("Password");
        String addressno = request.getParameter("addressno");
        String city = request.getParameter("city");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        String postalcode = request.getParameter("postalcode");
        String telnum = request.getParameter("telnum");

        DBConnect dbconnect = new DBConnect();
        dbconnect.update("INSERT INTO customer (customer_name, email, address_no, city, country, postal_code) VALUES('"+name+"','"+email+"','"+addressno+"', '"+city+"','"+country+"','"+postalcode+"')");
        int[] id = dbconnect.selectInt("Select LAST_INSERTID()", "customer_id");
        dbconnect.update("INSERT INTO customer_tel (customer_id, tel_no) VALUES('+id+', '"+telnum+"')");

    }

}
```

How can I set data to two tables from a same table?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. Do you mean insert into two tables in the same statement? You can't, but you can insert into two tables in the same transaction. And please use prepared statements with parameters

Answer (score 0):

I think `customer_id` is **AutoIncremented** in table `CUSTOMER` . I suggest that you create a `TRIGGER` on the table `CUSTOMER` so that everytime you insert a record on that table, it automatically gets that `customer_id` and *INSERTs* in on `customer_tel` table.

this link will guide you on creating a trigger: [Mysql Trigger After Insert](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-insert.shtml)

Comment: the incremented pk value is also readable from the executed statement (read api or google it, i've got no snippet to post right now :o). and both inserts should be run in the same transaction. you really don't want to use triggers for this purpose.

Comment: There is a form in the html page which takes information of the customer like name,address, bla bla bla and the telphone num...the details are inserted to a single table except the telephone num..the telephone number is inserted to another table...I need to know how to do that.